# Passing multiple lines to the Python interpreter via the '-c' option

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt

A single command passed to Python interpreter via '-c' option works perfectly:

```
$ python3 -c "print('Hi')"
Hi
$
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to send multiple lines (from the Windows command prompt), since the statements are grouped by indentation. Passing multiple lines in a single line will not work.

A Linux terminal supports multiple lines with newline character as argument:

```
$ python3 -c "
>import sys
>print(sys.argv[0])"
$ -c
```

***But in Windows it is not possible because the command get terminated with a newline***

```
$ python3 -c "

$
```

How do I make this work in the Windows command prompt?

I am just checking out the options of Python interpreter, so I am not looking for any workaround solution!

Comment: it is possible in linux terminal, my question is how to do the same in windows command prompt.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `^` operator here. Something like

```
C:\>python3 -c "print('Hai')"
Hai

C:\>python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)"
['-c']

C:\>python3 -c ^
More? "import sys; ^
More? print(sys.argv)"
['-c']
```

And,

```
C:\>python3 -c ^
More? "if 2*2 == 4: ^
More?     print('Testing')"
Testing
```

And,

```
C:\>python3 -c ^
More? "if True: ^
More?     print('First Line'); ^
More?     print('Second Line')"
First Line
Second Line
```

Comment: That's Python Syntax. You can try `if True: print("FirstLine"); print("SecondLine")` and it will work in the interpreter.